# Dividing a string in python

Tags: python, string

How do I tell a program to read /123/456/789/ as three separate strings to be handled individually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all your strings have this exact same format:

```
>>> "/123/456/789/".split("/")[1:-1]
['123', '456', '789']
```

You get your 3 strings from the list.

Comment: That's amazing. How do I get it to do the reverse?

Comment: If by reverse you mean get one string from the list of 3 strings:
"/".join(l), where l is the list of substrings

Answer (score 2):

```
test = "123/456/789"

for s in test.split('/'):
    print s
```

Comment: @shutupsquareThis would be a good solution if I only wanted it printed, but if I would want it to be assigned to a variable I would have to do:
test, test2 = "123/456/789", []

for s in test.split('/')"
   test2 += [s]

When it could all be solved with the above answer.

Answer (score 2):

an other solution if your string do not necessarry starts, or ends with '/', could be:

```
'/123/456/789/'.strip('/').split('/')
> ['123', '456', '789']
```